# detect form submission finish with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

As we know you cannot create a file download via ajax.

you can however submit a form which will create a download prompt.

I am generating quite a big file when the users presses a button so I display a "please wait" style message.

My question is,

How can I detect when the form submission has finished, hence the dialog box has been shown?

(this is to hide the message)

Comment: Who says you can't do file download with ajax?

Comment: Ok, you can with a lot of hacky work arounds using iframes etc, But what I mean is you can just do an ajax request and get a download prompt to appear to download the response because of browser security...

Comment: Not what I am asking, I have the prompt appearing, No matter which of these methods that is used my question stays the same, How can I tell when the prompt has actually appeared, hence the request has finished?

Comment: a bit confusing about that "prompt" is form generating it? is this a javascript prompt?

Comment: Its just the browser file download. its to the same effect as if you had entered a url in your browser that pointed to an .exe file.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Maybe you should try something like this

http://www.iamkumaran.com/xdownloader-a-flash-javascript-library/

See the demo how file download works and I hope it may help you.

Comment: bad link... also does it use flash?

Comment: Flash is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Place a redirect when form submission is successful. If redirect will hit the file which browser can't display - it will start download.

In my case I return JavaScript code from form submit handler, which form widget eval()s. That code could be a redirect to the fine which was just produced by the back-end.

Maybe my blog post about AJAX Forms best practices will be helpful:
http://agiletoolkit.org/blog/forms/

If you wish to keep things simple, then:

1. add form.onSubmit handler, it should prevent default action, collect form data and send to server. You can use some ajax submission plugin for jQuery.
2. server should parse data, prepare file and send back the name of the file to browser.
3. your JS code gets executed when transfer is complete (callback) and does redirect to the file through document.location.

In [Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/) it would be as simple as this:

```
$f=$p->add('MyForm');
if($f->isSubmitted()){
    $f->js()->univ()->location(prepare_file($f->getAllData()))->execute();
}
```